# converting (Ispy) C# EXE to android APK?

Tags: c#, apk, exe

I checked around and there's a possibility of converting an exe program to an apk if there is the source code, but nobody really tell me how this is done, is it just copy paste inside eclipse or is there a specific way of doing it ?

If somebody is kind enough to convert it to me i will be extremely grateful. 
the software i want to convert is called Ispy. Its an open source project so all the codes are there.

http://www.ispyconnect.com/source.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple solution. The app is written in c#, but the regular Android development tools uses Java. You may have some luck with [Monodroid](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid), but I assume you will have lots of trouble getting an application written for desktop screen size with mouse and keyboard running on an Android device.